# Infinite loop in Java program with graph and inner classes

Tags: java, graph, infinite-loop, inner-classes

Ok so my task is that given a list of Donations and a Set of Projects (Classes given below) I must see if all the projects can be funded by the donations. If they cannot, it must de-allocate all money allocated so far and return false. 
Donations have a list of projects that they can donate to and have a given amount.

I chose to implement this with a graph. Vertices represent a project and the connections are the donations they share with other projects. It is set up so that it cycles through the donations and donates 1 dollar at a time to each project it can fund. If a project cannot be fully funded but can transfer money from another project it is connected to by donations, transfer money from that project. If there is no possible way of funding all of the projects then de-allocate everything and return false.

My two problems are:
1) My test suite is entering an infinite loop when transfers are required. At the moment i'd be happy if someone could just locate my infinite loop problem and propose a fix to make it exit before i really work on getting the transfers part to work.

The two given classes don't need to be fixed, its just the first chunk of code that has the problem. I have no doubt as well that my graph, node and connector classes are not very good at all but they work at the moment. I'm just looking for a fix in the canAllocateHelper method.

Note: Sorry for posting so much code but i posted a similar question about 12 hours ago and i was told that i didn't give enough code for it to be debugged so i thought i'd just post everything.

My code:

```
package a2;

import java.util.*;

import a2.IterativeAllocator.Connector;
import a2.IterativeAllocator.Node;


public class IterativeAllocator {

    /**
     * @precondition: Neither of the inputs are null or contain null elements.
     *                The parameter donations is a list of distinct donations
     *                such that for each d in donations, d.getTotal() equals
     *                d.getUnspent(); and for each p in projects
     *                p.allocatedFunding() equals 0.
     * @postcondition: returns false if there no way to completely fund all of
     *                 the given projects using the donations, leaving both the
     *                 input list of donations and set of projects unmodified;
     *                 otherwise returns true and allocates to each project
     *                 funding from the donations. The allocation to each
     *                 project must be complete and may not violate the
     *                 conditions of the donations.
     */
    public static boolean canAllocate(List<Donation> donations,
            Set<Project> projects) {


        ArrayList<Node<Project>> nodes = getNodes(donations, projects);
        Graph<?> uniGraph = createGraph(nodes);

        if (donations.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        return canAllocateHelper(donations, projects, uniGraph, 0); 
    }

    // Helper Methods


    private static boolean canAllocateHelper(List<Donation> donations,
            Set<Project> projects, Graph graph, int index ) {

        Donation donation = donations.get(index);
        Set<Project> p = donation.getProjects();


        int count = countFullyFunded(projects);
        if (count == projects.size()) { return true; }

        if (donation.spent()) {
            if (index == donations.size() - 1) { return false; }
            return canAllocateHelper(donations, projects, graph, index + 1);
        }

        int pCount = countFullyFunded(p);
        if (pCount == p.size() && (index + 1) < donations.size() ) {
            return canAllocateHelper(donations, projects, graph, index + 1);
        }

        for (int i=0; i < graph.size(); i++) {
            Node<Project> tempNode = graph.getNode(i);
            Project tempProj = tempNode.getElement();


            if (donation.canBeUsedFor(tempProj)) {
                if (!tempProj.fullyFunded()) {
                    if (donation.spent()) {

                        LinkedList<Connector<Project>> conns = tempNode.getConnections();
                        for (int k=0; k<conns.size(); k++) {
                            tempProj.transfer(1, conns.get(k).getSecond().getElement());
                canAllocateHelper(donations, projects, graph, index);
                        }

                    }
                    tempProj.allocate(donation, 1);
                if (canAllocateHelper(donations, projects, graph, index)) {
                    return true;
                }
                    tempProj.deallocate(donation, 1);
                }



            }

        }

        return false;
    }


    private static ArrayList<Node<Project>> getNodes(List<Donation> donations, 
            Set<Project> projects) {

        ArrayList<Node<Project>> nodes = new ArrayList<Node<Project>>();
        Iterator<Project> pIterator = projects.iterator();

        while (pIterator.hasNext()) {
            Node<Project> node = new Node<Project>(pIterator.next());
            nodes.add(node);
        }

        // Iterate through donations to get an Array of connections
        for (int i=0; i < donations.size(); i++) {
            Set<Project> connections = donations.get(i).getProjects();
            ArrayList<Node<Project>> cArray = new ArrayList<Node<Project>>();
            Iterator<Project> cIterator = connections.iterator();
            while (cIterator.hasNext()) {
                Node<Project> temp = new Node<Project>(cIterator.next());
                cArray.add(temp);
            }
            // for each node, see if in cArray. If so, connect it
            for (int j=0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
                if ( cArray.contains(nodes.get(j))) {
                    for ( int k = 0; k < cArray.size(); k++) {
                        nodes.get(j).connect(cArray.get(k), 
                                donations.get(i).getTotal());
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return nodes;
    }



    private static Graph<?> createGraph(ArrayList<Node<Project>> nodes) {

        Graph<?> graph = new Graph<Object>();

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            graph.addNode(nodes.get(i));
        }

        return graph;
    }


    private static int countFullyFunded(Set<Project> projects) {

        Iterator<Project> projectsIterator = projects.iterator();
        int count = 0;
        while(projectsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Project proj = projectsIterator.next();
            if (proj.fullyFunded()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    return count;
    }



    // Private classes


    public static class Node<E> {

        private int count = 0;
        private E element;
        private int id;
        private LinkedList<Connector<E>> connections;

        public Node() {
            this(null);
        }

        public Node(E element) {
            this.element = element;
            id = count++;
            connections = new LinkedList<Connector<E>>();
        }

        public int getID() { 
            return id; 
            }
        public E getElement() { 
            return element; 
            }
        public void setElement(E elem) { 
            this.element = elem; 
            }


        public void connect(Node<E> newPoint, int cost) {
            Connector<E> a = new Connector<E>(this, newPoint, cost);
            if(!connections.contains(a)) {
                connections.add(a);
            }
        }

        public LinkedList<Connector<E>> getConnections() {
            return connections;
        }

        public void sortConnections() {
             Collections.sort(connections);
        }

        public Iterator<Connector<E>> iterator() {
            return connections.iterator();
        }

        public boolean equals(Node<E> other) {
            if(other.connections.size() != connections.size()) {
                return false;
            }

            LinkedList<Connector<E>> temp = new 
                    LinkedList<Connector<E>>(other.getConnections());
            return !(temp.retainAll(this.connections)); 
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.element.toString();
        }

    }

    public static class Connector<E> implements Comparable<Connector<E>>{
        private Node<E> first, second;
        private int dist;

        public Connector(Node<E> first, Node<E> second){ 
            this(first, second, 0);
            }

        public Connector(Node<E> first, Node<E> second, int dist){
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
            this.dist = dist;
        }

        public Node<E> getFirst(){
            return first;
            }
        public Node<E> getSecond(){
            return second;
            }
        public int getDistance(){
            return dist;
            }
        public void setDistance(int distance){
            this.dist = distance;
            }

        public boolean equals(Connector<E> other){
          return first.equals(other.getFirst()) &&
                         second.equals(other.getSecond()) &&
                         dist == other.getDistance();
        }

        public String toString(){ return "(" + first.getElement() +
            ", " + second.getElement() + "): " + dist; }

        public int compareTo(Connector<E> other){
            return this.dist - other.dist;

        }

    }


    private static class Graph<E> {

        private ArrayList<Node<E>> nodes;

        public Graph() {
            nodes = new ArrayList<Node<E>>();
        }

        public boolean addNode(Node<Project> node) {
            if (nodes.contains(node)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                nodes.add((Node<E>) node);
                return true;
            }
        }

        public Node<E> getNode(int index) {
            return nodes.get(index);
        }

        public int size() {
            return nodes.size();
        }

        public boolean equals(Graph<E> other) {

            if (other.size() != nodes.size()) {
                return false;
            }

            ArrayList<Node<E>> temp = new ArrayList<Node<E>>(other.nodes);
            return temp.retainAll(nodes);
        }
    }



}
```

The test Suite:

```
package a2.test;

import org.junit.*;

import java.util.*;

import a2.*;

/**
 * Some tests for the part2.IterativeAllocator.canAllocate method. A much more
 * extensive test suite will be used to mark your code, but this should get you
 * started writing your own tests to help you to debug your implementation.
 */
public class IterativeAllocatorTest {

    @Test
    public void basicTestTrue() {
        List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
        ArrayList<Donation> donations = new ArrayList<Donation>();
        projects.add(new Project("P0", 100));
        projects.add(new Project("P1", 100));
        projects.add(new Project("P2", 100));
        donations.add(new Donation("D0", 100, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(0), projects.get(1)))));
        donations.add(new Donation("D1", 100, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(1), projects.get(2)))));
        donations.add(new Donation("D2", 50, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(0)))));
        donations.add(new Donation("D3", 50, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(2)))));

        List<Donation> actualDonations = new ArrayList<>(donations);
        Set<Project> actualProjects = new HashSet<>(projects);
        Assert.assertTrue(IterativeAllocator.canAllocate(actualDonations,
                actualProjects));
        // no donations should be added or removed from the list of donations
        Assert.assertEquals(donations, actualDonations);
        // no projects should be added or removed from the set of projects
        Assert.assertEquals(new HashSet<>(projects), actualProjects);
        // allocation should be complete and valid
        checkCompleteAllocation(actualDonations, actualProjects);
    }

    @Test
    public void basicTestFalse() {
        List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
        ArrayList<Donation> donations = new ArrayList<Donation>();
        projects.add(new Project("P0", 100));
        projects.add(new Project("P1", 100));
        projects.add(new Project("P2", 100));
        donations.add(new Donation("D0", 100, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(0), projects.get(1), projects.get(2)))));
        donations.add(new Donation("D1", 200, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(0)))));

        List<Donation> actualDonations = new ArrayList<>(donations);
        Set<Project> actualProjects = new HashSet<>(projects);
        Assert.assertFalse(IterativeAllocator.canAllocate(actualDonations,
                actualProjects));
        // no donations should be added or removed from the list of donations
        Assert.assertEquals(donations, actualDonations);
        // no projects should be added or removed from the set of projects
        Assert.assertEquals(new HashSet<>(projects), actualProjects);
        // no allocations should have been made
        checkEmptyAllocation(actualDonations, actualProjects);
    }

    // basic no transfer test
    @Test
    public void noTransferTrue() {
        List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
        ArrayList<Donation> donations = new ArrayList<Donation>();
        projects.add(new Project("P0", 10));
        projects.add(new Project("P1", 10));
        projects.add(new Project("P2", 10));
        donations.add(new Donation("D0", 10, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(0), projects.get(1)))));
        donations.add(new Donation("D1", 10, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(1), projects.get(2)))));
        donations.add(new Donation("D2", 5, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(0)))));
        donations.add(new Donation("D3", 5, new HashSet<Project>(Arrays
                .asList(projects.get(2)))));

        List<Donation> actualDonations = new ArrayList<>(donations);
        Set<Project> actualProjects = new HashSet<>(projects);
        Assert.assertTrue(IterativeAllocator.canAllocate(actualDonations,
                actualProjects));
        // no donations should be added or removed from the list of donations
        Assert.assertEquals(donations, actualDonations);
        // no projects should be added or removed from the set of projects
        Assert.assertEquals(new HashSet<>(projects), actualProjects);
        // allocation should be complete and valid
        checkCompleteAllocation(actualDonations, actualProjects);
    }

    // helper methods

    /**
     * Helper method to check that each project has been completely allocated by
     * the given donations, and that the total spent on each donation is equal
     * to that spent on the given projects.
     **/
    private void checkCompleteAllocation(List<Donation> donations,
            Set<Project> projects) {

        // the amount spent from each donation by all of the combined projects
        Map<Donation, Integer> totalSpent = new HashMap<>();

        // check that each project has been completely (and properly) allocated
        // and calculate totalSpent
        for (Project p : projects) {
            Assert.assertTrue(p.fullyFunded());
            for (Map.Entry<Donation, Integer> allocation : p.getAllocations()
                    .entrySet()) {
                Donation d = allocation.getKey();
                int amount = allocation.getValue();
                Assert.assertTrue(amount > 0);
                Assert.assertTrue(d.canBeUsedFor(p));
                Assert.assertTrue(donations.contains(d));
                if (totalSpent.containsKey(d)) {
                    totalSpent.put(d, totalSpent.get(d) + amount);
                } else {
                    totalSpent.put(d, amount);
                }
            }
        }

        // check that the remaining funds in each donation are correct, assuming
        // that no funds were spent from each donation to begin with.
        for (Donation d : donations) {
            if (totalSpent.containsKey(d)) {
                Assert.assertTrue(d.getUnspent() >= 0);
                Assert.assertEquals(d.getUnspent(),
                        d.getTotal() - totalSpent.get(d));
            } else {
                Assert.assertEquals(d.getUnspent(), d.getTotal());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to check that no allocations have been made for any project
     * in projects and that all donations have not been spent at all.
     **/
    private void checkEmptyAllocation(List<Donation> donations,
            Set<Project> projects) {
        for (Project p : projects) {
            Assert.assertEquals(p.getCost(), p.neededFunds());
        }
        for (Donation d : donations) {
            Assert.assertEquals(d.getUnspent(), d.getTotal());
        }
    }
}
```

Donation Class:

```
package a2;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * A class representing a donation. A donation has a name, the total amount of
 * the donation, the unspent portion of the donation and a set of projects that
 * the donation may be spent on.
 * 
 * DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE IN ANY WAY.
 */

public class Donation {

    // name of donation
    private String name;
    // total donation amount
    private int total;
    // amount of donation that has not yet been spent
    private int unspent;
    // projects that the funds from this donation could be spent on
    private Set<Project> projects;

    /*
     * invariant: name != null && total > 0 && 0 <= unspent <= total &&
     * projects!=null
     */

    /**
     * @precondition: name!= null && total > 0 && projects != null
     * @postcondition: creates a new donation with given name, total donation
     *                 amount and projects that this donation could be spent on.
     *                 No funds from the donation have initially been spent.
     */
    public Donation(String name, int total, Set<Project> projects) {
        assert name != null && projects != null && total > 0;

        this.name = name;
        this.total = total;
        this.projects = projects;
        this.unspent = total;
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns the total amount of this donation.
     */
    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns the amount of this donation that hasn't been
     *                 spent yet.
     */
    public int getUnspent() {
        return unspent;
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns true iff this donation has been totally spent.
     */
    public boolean spent() {
        return (unspent == 0);
    }

    /**
     * @precondition: 0 <= cost <= getUnspent()
     * @postcondition: removes cost from the amount of available funds for this
     *                 donation. The only method that should call this one
     *                 directly is the allocate method from the Project class.
     *                 (That is, it should only be executed as part of an
     *                 allocation of these funds to a particular project.)
     */
    public void spend(int cost) {
        assert 0 <= cost && cost <= unspent;
        unspent = unspent - cost;
    }

    /**
     * @precondition: 0 <= cost <= total - getUnspent()
     * @postcondition: adds cost back to the available funds for this donation.
     *                 The only method that should call this one directly is the
     *                 deallocate method from the Project class. (That is, it
     *                 should only be executed as part of the deallocation of
     *                 these funds from a particular project.)
     */
    public void unspend(int cost) {
        assert 0 <= cost && cost <= total - unspent;
        unspent = unspent + cost;
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns true iff this donation is allowed to be spent on
     *                 the given project.
     */
    public boolean canBeUsedFor(Project project) {
        return projects.contains(project);
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns a (shallow copy of) the set of the projects for
     *                 this donation.
     */
    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return new HashSet<>(projects);
    }
}
```

Project Class:

```
package a2;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * A class representing a project and its current allocation of funds.
 * 
 * DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE IN ANY WAY.
 */

public class Project {

    private String name; // name of project
    private int cost; // total cost of the project
    private int allocatedFunding; // sum of the funds currently allocated
    private Map<Donation, Integer> allocations; // funds currently allocated

    /*
     * invariant:
     * 
     *  cost > 0 && allocatedFunding >= 0 && allocatedFunding <= cost &&
     * 
     *  allocations != null && name != null &&
     * 
     *  for each entry (d, x) in allocations, 
     *      d!=null && x>0 && d.canBeUsedFor(this) &&
     * 
     *  allocatedFunding is the sum of values in the allocations map
     */

    /**
     * @precondition: name!= null && cost > 0
     * @postcondition: creates a new project with given name and cost and an
     *                 initially empty allocation of funds.
     */
    public Project(String name, int cost) {
        assert (name != null && cost > 0);
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        allocations = new HashMap<Donation, Integer>();
        allocatedFunding = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns the total cost of the project.
     */
    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns true if and only if the allocated funds are equal
     *                 to the total cost of the project.
     */
    public boolean fullyFunded() {
        return (cost == allocatedFunding);
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns the amount of money that is needed to completely
     *                 fund the project.
     */
    public int neededFunds() {
        return (cost - allocatedFunding);
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns the amount of money currently allocated to the
     *                 project.
     */
    public int allocatedFunding() {
        return allocatedFunding;
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: returns (a shallow copy of) the current allocations to
     *                 the project. (Changing the returned map won't change the
     *                 allocations of the project. To do that use the
     *                 allocation, deallocation or transfer methods of this
     *                 class.)
     */
    public Map<Donation, Integer> getAllocations() {
        return new HashMap<>(allocations);
    }

    /**
     * @precondition: donation!=null && 0 < amount <= donation.getUnspent() &&
     *                amount <= neededFunds() donation.canBeUsedFor(this)
     * @postcondition: spends the given amount of money from the donation by
     *                 allocating it to this project.
     */
    public void allocate(Donation donation, int amount) {
        assert donation != null;
        assert 0 < amount && amount <= donation.getUnspent()
                && amount <= neededFunds() && donation.canBeUsedFor(this);

        addToAllocations(donation, amount);
        donation.spend(amount);
    }

    private void addToAllocations(Donation donation, int amount) {
        Integer existingAmount = allocations.get(donation);
        if (existingAmount == null) {
            existingAmount = 0;
        }
        allocations.put(donation, amount + existingAmount);
        allocatedFunding += amount;
    }

    /**
     * @precondition: donation!=null && allocations.containsKey(donation) &&
     *                allocations.get(donation) >= amount
     * @postcondition: puts the given amount of money back into the unspent
     *                 funds for the donation and removes it from the allocation
     *                 to this project.
     */
    public void deallocate(Donation donation, int amount) {
        assert donation != null;
        assert allocations.containsKey(donation);
        assert allocations.get(donation) >= amount;

        removeFromAllocations(donation, amount);
        donation.unspend(amount);
    }

    /**
     * @postcondition: deallocates all allocations to this project.
     */
    public void deallocateAll() {
        for (Map.Entry<Donation, Integer> entry : allocations.entrySet()) {
            Donation d = entry.getKey();
            int amount = entry.getValue();
            d.unspend(amount);
            allocatedFunding -= amount;
        }
        allocations.clear();
    }

    private void removeFromAllocations(Donation donation, int amount) {
        int existingAmount = allocations.get(donation);
        if (existingAmount > amount) {
            allocations.put(donation, existingAmount - amount);
        } else {
            allocations.remove(donation);
        }
        allocatedFunding -= amount;
    }

    /**
     * @precondition: amount <= neededFunds() && the given amount of money may
     *                be transferred from the source project to this project
     * @postcondition: transfers $amount from source project to this project.
     */
    public void transfer(int amount, Project source) {
        assert amount <= neededFunds();

        Iterator<Map.Entry<Donation, Integer>> it = source.allocations
                .entrySet().iterator();
        Map.Entry<Donation, Integer> entry;
        while (it.hasNext() && amount > 0) {
            entry = it.next();
            if (entry.getKey().canBeUsedFor(this)) {
                int transferAmount = Math.min(amount, entry.getValue());
                // deallocate transferAmount from source project
                entry.setValue(entry.getValue() - transferAmount);
                source.allocatedFunding -= transferAmount;
                if (entry.getValue() == 0) {
                    it.remove();
                }
                // allocate transfer amount to this project
                this.addToAllocations(entry.getKey(), transferAmount);
                // update the amount that we have left to transfer
                amount = amount - transferAmount;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you heard of our mvce? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It's makes questions like these much easier for us to help you with, right now, it's hard to dig through all this code without getting lost. I recommend editing your code.

Comment: Ok well the two class files are fine. I was given those and they aren't to be edited. It's just the main code that I need help with and it's pretty much needed as I wrote two inner classes to use and the whole code is creating the problem when tested against a particular test. I'm not sure how I could condense this and reproduce the same problem

Comment: Hmmmm, I think you're right, ok well give me a sec to digest what's going on here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really into your code but there is one thing in it that's a common reason for infinite loops.
At some parts in your `canAllocateHelper(donations, projects, graph, index)` function you use recursion. First in to if-conditions.

```
if (donation.spent()) {
    if (index == donations.size() - 1) { return false; }
    return canAllocateHelper(donations, projects, graph, index + 1);
}

int pCount = countFullyFunded(p);
if (pCount == p.size() && (index + 1) < donations.size() ) {
    return canAllocateHelper(donations, projects, graph, index + 1);
}
```

That's okay because you call the function again with an incremented index.
But later in the for-loop you call the function again without an incremented index.
Using recursion evertytime with the same function parameters leads to infinite loops in a lot of cases.

Comment: Yeah these two bits you posted are the if statements to increment through the donations. The last one is to run the exact same code again as it allocates one dollar at a time. once the donation is spent (donation.spent()) or the count of fully funded projects for the donation is met, then it increments to the next donation. Although as you say, it is possible that this is the reason for the infinite loop as it may be de-allocating from a failure and then triggering the increment instead of just exiting on a failure

Comment: It's too much code to understand ina short time, but a last idea is, that the reason is only the fourth recursion, where you do:

`tempProj.allocate(donation, 1);
if (canAllocateHelper(donations, projects, graph, index)) {
    return true;
}
tempProj.deallocate(donation, 1);`

You allocate an amount to the project, call the function and deallocate it shortly after. So in fact nothing has changed.
However this is all I can think of without trying to fully understand your code.